# How to hide container div title when hovering inner elements?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i work with react and have a div with background image inserted from the css. the div also has a title and several elements inside. when hovering over the div the title is shown, the problem is that it is shown also when hovering over the inner elements: h1, button, etc. 
how to allow this functionality to work on the div but not on it's inner elements.

i tried overriding the div title with the inner elements title: title={""},
i tried overriding it with aria-label, it didn't work also. i tried taking out the image into it's own element rather than from the css, but it requires css restructuring and i'd rather find a solution in the jsx.

```
    const {pageTitle, subTitle, mainImage, alternativeText} = this.props;;
    const containerStyles = { background: "url(" + mainImage + ") center center / cover no-repeat"};
    return (
        <div style={containerStyles} className={"heroLanding"} title={alternativeText}>
            <div className={"landingContainer"}>
                <h1 className={"landingTitle"}>
                    <span className={"landingTitle_small"}> {pageTitle} </span>
                    {subTitle}
                </h1>
                <div className={"heroLanding-listContainer"}>
                    <HeroList />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How does title={alternativeText} even display on the screen?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo like tooltip, like 'alt' attribute of img tag when hovering

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. And you're saying you want to essentially get rid of that/hide it when the user hovers over the image correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be making use of some really simple event-listeners here. Assuming you are using a class-component, we can use a state-variable to feed the value to the div's title prop. When we enter the landingContainer div, we will give that title an empty-string. When we leave the landingContainer div, we will give the title back its original prop value.

```
class Image extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            title: props.alternativeText
        }
    }

  handleOnMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({
      title: '',
    })
  }

  handleOnMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      title: this.props.alternativeText,
    })
  }


    render(){
    const {pageTitle, subTitle, mainImage, alternativeText} = this.props;;
    const containerStyles = { background: "url(" + mainImage + ") center center / cover no-repeat"};
    return (
        <div style={containerStyles} className={"heroLanding"} title={this.state.title}>
            <div 
                 className={"landingContainer"} 
                 onMouseEnter={this.handleOnMouseEnter} 
                 onMouseLeave={this.handleOnMouseLeave}
            >
                <h1 className={"landingTitle"}>
                    <span className={"landingTitle_small"}> {pageTitle} </span>
                    {subTitle}
                </h1>
                <div className={"heroLanding-listContainer"}>
                    <HeroList />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
}
```

Here's a sandbox to show you how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/zxpnk301pl

Comment: it works partially. there's an <h1> in the middle of the container div, and hovering over the container div left or right horizontally from the <h1> doesn't show the title. it's because the h1 is in the middle and it's horizontal margin is spread all over the screen. so i  enter the onMouseEnterHandler(). any suggestions ? i tried to use flex but it didn't help.

Comment: @UNlessofficialchannel sorry I was asleep went you commented. were you able to get this to work?